# Yeoman, angular & bootstrap - how to include new bootstrap javascript components with Bower?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, yeoman, bower

`tooltip.js` is not included in Bootstrap by default but I want to add it to an Yoeman-scaffolded app using Bower. I've tried adding it to `bower.json` in the `main` array:

```
"main": [
"less/bootstrap.less",
"dist/css/bootstrap.css",
"dist/js/bootstrap.js",
"js/tooltip.js",
"dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot",
"dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg",
"dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf",
"dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff"
],
```

But this is not automatically included in the list of scripts within `<!-- bower:js -->` in `index.html`. How do I update this list of dependencies and have bower rebuild this list? Is there a way of doing this without manually adding the requirement to `bower.json` ?

Comment: did you rerun bower install after editing the bower.json?

Comment: bower install what? i didn't install bootstrap via bower initially as it was included as part of the angular-seed in yeoman

Comment: adding something to the bower.json doesn't include it in the project, It;s just one line in the file. If you've edited bower.json to contain something new, in the command line navigate to the directory that contains the bower.json and run 'bower install'. This will detect the new component to be added, download and add the files and include in your index.html

Comment: this isn't updating anything. to be clear, i've added `"js/tooltip.js"` to the `bower.json` within `bower_components/bootstrap` and then run `bower install` (and `bower install --save`) from within the same folder as that `bower.json` file. Nothing happens! Thanks for helping.

Comment: I wouldn't advise editing the bower.json nested inside the bootstrap folder. This is a list of dependencies for the bootstrap project. You're looking to add something to your project so you should add it into the dependencies of the bower.json in the root of your project and then run bower install

Comment: hmmm... i think the problem here is tooltip.js is not a package registered with bower, it's just an extension for bootstrap. so if i add it to dependencies it's not going to work because of that (according to https://github.com/bower/bower.json-spec#name). this is just about extending the functionality of bootstrap, not installing a package via bower i suppose. i'm just going to include it manually for the time being and see if grunt figures it out at build...

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone finds this, the fix was to add a relative path to the `tooltip.js` file in the app's main `bower.json` file as so:

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "tooltip": "./bower_components/bootstrap/js/tooltip.js"
},
```

Install the dependency to bower with `bower install --save` and then rebuild the bower included files in index.html by calling `grunt wiredep`.